# POI is not recognised

Tags: java, apache-poi

Im using struts application. I want to work on reports. So going to try POI. I got this jar file poi-3.6-20091214.jar and put them in web-inf/lib folder.When i try using them in class file poi is not recognised. Im trying below...

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet; 
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook; //.. 
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet"); //Create a new row in current sheet 
Row row = sheet.createRow(0); //Create a new cell in current row
Cell cell = row.createCell(0); //Set value to new value 
cell.setCellValue("Blahblah");
```

But import itself wouldnt work.Any idea?

Comment: In this inside eclipse workspace?

Comment: POI 3.6 is 2 years old, is there a reason why you're not using the latest version?

Comment: ok i am working woith jDev. So i had to go add projects independently. Now it works. BTW now, Row, Cell is not working. Its getting red underline. Does that mean it doesnt come with that package?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added into the eclipse lib path?
another thing: use poi 3.8, is more recent. Why start with an old release?

Answer (score 0):

I think its `HSSFRow` & `HSSFCell` and not `Row` and `Cell`. These are included in the jar.

One point to consider using POI is that the same code will not be able to handle both `.xls` and `.xlsx` file formats.

missed this: it will be `XSSF` if you are using `.xlsx` files and `HSSF` for `.xls` file format.

Comment: That's incorrect - all recent POI releases include both the interfaces (eg `Row`) along with the HSSF implementations in the main jar